# How to visible phone attribute on customer registration page

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, registration

I have show phone attribute on registration page. How can i do that [image]

Like email in sign-in information [image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the **phone** is somehow complex, because it is part of the `Address` entity, not the `Customer` entity (it would be easier to add any of the Customer fields, like `Middle Name`, `Date of Birth` or `Gender`).

So you can add additional fields to the "Create New Customer Account" form by overriding the `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/additionalinfocustomer.phtml` template.

But you would need to figure out how to save it correctly, so it can be displayed as the screenshot you attached. I guess it is not possible to save it if you don't create the whole address for the customer (along with address, city, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your great response then any thing possiblity to add phone number because i have  use a phone number in rest api for that resson i tried this. And i am new in magento.